Converting two dataframe columns to a combined vector with additional strings
In
    df <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:10], B=LETTERS[11:20])
    
    z <- paste(df$A, "=", df$B)
    chr [1:10] "A = K" "B = L" "C = M" "D = N" "E = O" "F = P" "G = Q" "H = R" "I = S" "J = T"

,
how can i add a comma (",") between each components the vector z?
Desired output
c("A = K", "B = L", "C = M",......) and so on.
Thank you!

What? Where exactly would you put a comma? What do you need this for?

See the desired output. I need it for a label argument in ggplot

It is unclear why z isn't the desired output. It is a character vector identical to your desired output.

I think your question is not how to create the vector, but how to label the plot correctly.
A classic xy problem.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

As privious comments suggest, a lot of quetions here. to achive your desired output you could else do : z <- paste(df$A, "=", df$B, collapse = ",") however its hard to understand why you would like to do.

Maybe you are looking for ´dput´?

Here are two alternatives:
# 1
toString(z)

#2
paste(z, collapse = ", ")

ggplot
To create a title from that in ggplot using (1), say:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + ggtitle(toString(z))

(continued after graph)

or if the upper left corner is preferred:
ggplot(BOD, aes(Time, demand)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate("text", x=-Inf, y=Inf, label=toString(z), hjust=0, vjust=0.9, cex=3) 


Note
Input as shown in question
df <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:10], B=LETTERS[11:20])
z <- paste(df$A, "=", df$B)


nothing can be shorter than toString, cheers! :)
